# Using == in javascript always false

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I use a javascript function to change my HTML background color by DI state

here's my code

```
function pageData() {
var DI1_STATE =document.getElementById('DI1').textContent;   //load DI1
console.log(DI1_STATE);                                      //DI1_STATE= ON or OFF(TYPEOF = String)  
console.log(DI1_STATE=='ON');                                //ALWAYS FLASE
console.log(DI1_STATE=='OFF');                               //ALWAYS FLASE
var result = DI1_STATE.localeCompare('ON');                  //WORK  preset 1(TRUE) or -1(FLASE)
console.log(result);
if (DI1_STATE == 'ON'){
document.getElementById('DI1').style.backgroundColor = 'Coral';
document.getElementById('DI1').style.color = 'White';}
else{
document.getElementById('DI1').style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
document.getElementById('DI1').style.color = 'black';}}
```

I wonder why == is not work

the  whole Html code
I made the server at a microchip，i update the "DI1" by getsensorDATA3()

and the server command below

Comment: Please provide your html code

Comment: are you sure its not `OFF ` or `ON `? notice the space

Comment: There's probably whitespace around the text: Check `DI1_STATE.length` and `DI1_STATE.trim().length`

Answer (score 2):

You always have to check for line breaks, spaces or other non visible characters when comparing string values from html elements. Try

```
var DI1_STATE =document.getElementById('DI1').textContent.trim()
```

`localeCompare` is used to determine sort order and only reports back if the reference string comes before or after the comparison string (in the sort order):

- Negative when the referenceStr occurs before compareString
- Positive when the referenceStr occurs after compareString
- Returns 0 if they are equivalent

You might use it like `array.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a));`

Tests....

```js
let test = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;
console.log('"' + test + '"') 
console.log('test == "TEST"', test == "TEST") // false
console.log('test.localeCompare("TEST")', test.localeCompare("TEST")) // 1  

test = test.trim();

console.log('test == "TEST"', test == "TEST") // true
console.log('test.localeCompare("TEST")', test.localeCompare("TEST")) // 0
```

```html
<textarea>TEST </textarea>
```